# Storing\Reading an external email template with aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have mailgun wired up in my aspnet core site to fire off emails, but I really want the "Template" to be stored externally on the file system (ideally the wwwroot) so I can quickly change\tweak without needing to re-publish anything.

How would I accomplish something like this?

Regards,
Steve

Comment: I use Razor with strongly typed models to render email, so the templates are just .cshtml files. you can see [my code here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Components/Messaging/SiteEmailMessageSender.cs) which sends emails, it invokes this [ViewRenderer](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Web.Common/Razor/ViewRenderer.cs), and you can see my Razor template [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/tree/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Views/Sys/Shared/EmailTemplates)

Comment: OH! RenderViewAsString Genious!  Do you want to submit an answer on this so I can accept\vote it up?

Comment: done, I was little reluctant to post it as an answer because answers that just link to stuff are little frowned upon here, but if it gave you what you need then I guess it is a good enough answer

Comment: Better to give you credit for an answer and for the next person to see it answered. Thx again, saved my butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Razor with strongly typed models to render email, so the templates are just .cshtml files.

you can see my [code here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Components/Messaging/SiteEmailMessageSender.cs) which sends emails, it invokes this [ViewRenderer](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Web.Common/Razor/ViewRenderer.cs), and you can see my [Razor templates here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/tree/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Views/Sys/Shared/EmailTemplates)

the linked examples use simple primitive types for the models, but I'm using more elaborate view models with the same technique in my other projects